# How to search twitter.com/search and parse the data in android

Tags: android, search, twitter

I have been dealing with a twitter application in android. I used Oauth authentication and did some search for a given keyword.

The problem is **rate limit**.  I can't perform to many searches.

Well after an exhaust search I came across with that link:[Using the Search API](https://support.twitter.com/entries/160385-how-do-i-get-whitelisted)

It says that:

> As users, the best thing for you to do is perform your search from twitter.com/search

Then I found an application in Google Play [Twitter Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamison.searchtwitter&hl=en) which doesn't even use authentication and performs unlimited searches.

I doubt `Twitter Search` developer  has used that logic.

- Would it be possible to make the search directly from `twitter.com/search` ?
- If yes, what libraries/methods/ways should I follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be possible to make the search directly from
>   twitter.com/search ?

Technically yes, but that should be avoided if at all possible. You would have to parse the HTML and that is a both slow and error prone process.

> What libraries/methods/ways should I follow?

You should stick to the official API. I realise that this rate limit is kind of in the way, but I am confident you can mitigate the problem by reducing the overall amount of calls to the API and  by more efficiently using each call. You have to remember that this is the official Twitter API. Twitter certainly wants for Twitter apps to be good and awesome and while the rate limit of 100 calls per hour seems pretty low it should normally be more than enough. Should the rate limit be reached anyway you just need some proper error handling. I know for a fact that most third party twitter apps just kind of freeze their content when reaching the rate limit. An error is displayed to inform the user that he cannot update anymore for an hour, but he can still continue using the app as before with all the cached data from the previous calls.

Since you haven't posted any code I am not sure what else to tell you just try to be smart about each call. Use cached data as much as possible and only perform API calls when absolutely necessary.

---

**EDIT:** I think parsing data from **https://mobile.twitter.com/search** would be best in your case. Just look for the div with the class `timeline`. Every `<table />` in this div contains one tweet. It shouldn't be that difficult to parse.

I tested it using [**HtmlCleaner**](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/index.php):

```
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
TagNode root = cleaner.clean("https://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=asdf");
... // Filter out div with class "timeline"
List<? extends TagNode> tweets = timeLineDiv.getElementListByAttValue("class", "tweet", false, true);
```

Comment: Hello my friend. I do realize that twitter wants its API to be used. I have discussed this problem over and over with my company. As a part of this project I have included a search button which enables users to  get the top tweets for a keyword. And that means I have to get all tweets, sort them ... and indeed this process is a kinda of slow. And there isn't too much chances to use cached data, since it only searches. Well it would make sense for me to navigate through the used activities from previous calls. But I'm afraid it would not be the case for all users. Instead I thought to make ...

Comment: ... the searches directly from the twitter webpage. To be more precise from `mobile.twitter.com` and this is because it would take less memory to load and would be much faster. And as for the speed the tweets there are already top tweets, which means I don't need to sort them anymore - just parse them. And it has also the benefit where I would not run in `Rate Limit` error. In a few words it best matches my requirement. And for parsing I have thought about [jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

Comment: Very well, just be careful when parsing the HTML. I can also recommend [**HtmlCleaner**](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/). I've used it a couple times now to parse HTML.